# wikitext to xml

Tags: java, xml, wiki, mediawiki

Is there a way to convert [wikitext](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aWikitext_examples) data into simple XML in a Java application?

Input example:

```
  == A section ==
  this is some text...           

{{MyTemplate
|attr1=some value
|attr2=some other value
      ...
```

Output example:

```
<section title='A section'>this is some text...</section>
<ValueDescription attr1='some value' attr2='some other value' ...>
```

It seems like a trivial task but I couldn't find a library to do it in Java.

Mulone

Comment: The full mediawiki syntax is quite complicated, so I wouldn't be surprised if the only fully-functioning parser was inside mediawiki itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML has a tree structure, wikitext for the most part does not. E. g. this is fully legal:

```
== A section {{DoubleEqual{{echo|Sign}}}}
```

The template syntax itself is hierarchical, and MediaWiki itself transforms it to XML (you can use [Special:ExpandTemplates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aExpandTemplates?contexttitle=&input===%20A%20section%20==%0D%0Athis%20is%20some%20text...%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%7B%7BMyTemplate%0D%0A%7Cattr1=some%20value%0D%0A%7Cattr2=some%20other%20value%0D%0A%7D%7D&generate_xml=1) to check it out), but the rest of the syntax is much too loose for XML or other formal descriptions like a context-free grammar.

There is a [rewrite effort](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikitext.next) going on to turn wikitext into a standard, parseable language, but don't expect it to end anytime soon.

Comment: you're right! it's a bit of a paradox to me, but it's easier to process wiki pages from the generated (and potentially messy) html than from the wikitext source.

Answer (score 0):

http://sweble.org/wiki/Wikitext-parser/ they have a properly done parser, but I think there is no XML output for the AST yet.

@Tgr: Syntactically it is not really compatible with a Tree but semantically it is.

And yes, handling Wikitext is a huge mess.